# Integrate a PDF over a set

Tags: calculus, statistics

This is part of a proof of Chebyshev's inequality, but there's one line I'm just trying to clarify my intuition of:

$f(x)$ is the pdf and $g(x)$ is a non-negative function.

$$  \int\limits_{x: g(x) \ge k} f(x) \ dx = P(g(X) \ge k) $$

Am I right in saying that by integrating a PDF over a set, we're finding the probability that this set occurs?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. In general any time you integrate a PDF over a set, you are getting the probability of that set with respect to the PDF.